# Keep me in/under your prayer

Tags: prepositions

Someone said me, " keep me under your prayer."
I think, i would be" keep me in your prayer"
Not "under" in "keep me under your prayer"
I am quite confused in this connection.
So, please inform me the right answer.

Comment: The normal expression would be "Keep me in your prayers" - keep me in the (mental) list of subjects you pray about regularly.

Comment: Hello Zafor,  Can you provide more context.  Who was the "someone"?  A friend? A teacher? A native speaker of English?  What was the context?  Did the context suggest that they were asking you to pray for them?

Comment: [correction: Someone **said to me**]

Comment: If you are a politician, especially in America, you always keep unfortunates "in your thoughts and prayers". What advantage this brings to the unfortunates has yet to be determined. But that's the drill!

Answer (score 1):

You're right; [this graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+your+prayers%2Cunder+your+prayers&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20your%20prayers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunder%20your%20prayers%3B%2Cc0) shows that the phrase "in your prayers" is much more common than "under your prayers."

However, it can be common (especially in evangelical Christian cultures) to use metaphorical prepositions about prayer that position the prayer "over" the subject of prayer, usually with implied metaphors of a protective shield or "covering." It is not unusual to talk of "covering [something or someone] in prayer" (see [these Google Books results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cover+in+prayer%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBu6piSuzRKqPfltgkaDZBzprVb3hg:1647283164831&tbas=0&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL-4j_n8b2AhXGl2oFHWUACaIQpwV6BAgBECc&biw=2048&bih=1016&dpr=2)), or to "pray **over** [something or someone]." The phrase "pray over" is still [much less common than "pray for,"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pray+for%2Cpray+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpray%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpray%20over%3B%2Cc0) but it could help explain what you heard.